# d3.js json structure add data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-virtualization

I'm drawing a pie chart with two simple values: label and value.
This is my json:

```
{
"valuecase": {
    "times": [
        {"label": "label", "value":5},
        {"label": "label", "value":13}
    ],
    "record": [
        {"label": "label", "value":5},
        {"label": "label", "value":13}
    ]
}
```

}

I'm not sure it's the best structure, in fact d3.js I can't call data value. This is my code:

```
d3.json("my.json", function(json) {
data = json.valuecase;
...selectAll("path")
.data(pie(dataset.times)) //*** How call the array, only value data??
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of values to the pie()...   You can try 
d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {return d.value; });  ...

```
d3.json("myjson.json", function(json) {

    var data = json.valuecase

    var w = 300,                           
    h = 300,   
    r = 100, 
    color = d3.scale.category20c();         
var vis = d3.select("body")
.append("svg:svg")             
.data([data.times])                   
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g")                
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")    

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()              
        .outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()                   
  .value(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.value; });    
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     
  .data(pie)                          
  .enter()        
  .append("svg:g")        
  .attr("class", "slice");
arcs.append("svg:path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) 
  .attr("d", arc);                                
arcs.append("svg:text")                                     
  .attr("transform", function(d) {                    
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = r;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";        
        })
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")                                      
  .text(function(d, i) { return data.times[i].value; });        
});
```